# Are there any MySQL version limitations for Zend\Db?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, zend-db

I'm using MySQL `5.5.*` and want to upgrade it to the currently newest version `5.7.*`.

**Are there any version related issues or limitations of the MySQL adapter of `Zend\Db` known?**

Answer (score 0):

if your on production server, its good to be stay for a little while, because some fw/software and platform not jus ready yet to use newer version of mysql based on: [Pimcore](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/356), [Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/release-notes), [glpi](https://github.com/glpi-project/glpi/issues/627) issues for example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, there are some features in other software and Zend Server is "working with MySQL 5.7 is experimental and needs specific configuration". But I asked about a single specific framework. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @automatix your welcome, actually i dig up again about zf but it seems nothing reported yet (hopefully). sorry thats all i found :)